# Can I create an Android app using Xamarin only

Tags: xamarin

I'm a Windows developer and have written all sorts of windows client applications using C++ and C#. I wanted to write an Android app and put it on the Google Store, but I'm only equipped with Visual Studio.

I wanted to ask if it is realistic to think that I can create an app, from scratch, including engine and UI using Xamarin only. I saw there are a few Xamarin samples out there, but I didn't want to start only to find out that it's not enough for some reason.

Currently I'm struggling a bit in getting my environment right, but thought I'd throw this question here to you guys ... Maybe it's not even worth starting?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes... between C#F#, NDK-based C/C++, XPATH/XML transforms for Binding Java libraries and completely using msbuild to produce an `.apk`, yes you can do that in VS. Of course behind the scenes it is using the Android SDK to do a good part of that, but in general Xamarin abstracts you away from that. Personally I have been using Xamarin (and MonoDroid) for 7 years and do find myself in Android Studio often for various reasons (converting C#2Java and NDK-based C++ for performance reason, UI design (the designer in VS blows) working around Xamarin.Android bugs, etc..)....

Comment: Thanks. If i need a UI that is conformed of images that the user will drag around the screen, is Xamarin enough to accomplish that?

Comment: If you can do it in Android via Java/Kotlin/NDK-Based C/C++ then basically you can do it with Xamarin.Android... You, of course, have to provide the coding 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Xamarin can be used to develop Android apps from scratch. Xamarin has two main libraries that help with this.

Xamarin.Android will give you access to all the Android APIs directly from c#. Note that you still need to know the basic Android concepts like what is an Activity and an Intent.
The other library is Xamarin.Forms. It is a cross-platform  library that will  give you a basic set of UI controls and widgets that you declare usong an xml syntax, and program with C#. This library has a few limitations, but you can also use the features of Xamarin.Android alongside it to get at the missing features.

Some advice: if possible, develop and debug directly on an Android tablet. Android emulators are not that good and hard to configure. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that does help. I do see that the emulator that i currently am trying to use is buggy and slow - totally different than the Windows phone development i've done. But if I use and Android tablet, then it'll be w/out VS ..

Comment: No, what I mean is, that you can use your Android tablet as a replacement for the emulator. Development is still done in VS, you just use the tablet for debugging and running the app. How to set it up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/debug-on-device?tabs=windows

Comment: The emulator can also be sped up by using hardware acceleration. This is provided by a tool named HAXM, a tool that can be downloaded with the SDK Manager from Android. This works only on PCs with Intel processors however.

Comment: Very helpful!! Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of Xamarin you can use.

Xamarin Forms : Which is the unified version that use XAML for the UI. It is very recommended to use this if you are building a simple application.

Xamarin Native : The "native" version of platform that are written in C#, if you want to create Android-only apps, I really recommend this, since it's very similar with the native Android code, but it's wrapped using C# (You can still using nuget package).